# Help implementing Swiss pairing algorithm in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

All,

One of the steps in Swiss pairing algorithm needs to create groups of players having the same score.

```
E.x.
 P1 - 3
 P2 - 3
 P3 - 2
 P4 - 1
 P5 - 1
 P6 - 1
```

So this should create 3 groups i.e. 3 arrays consisting Array 1: {P1, P2} ; Array 2: {P3} ; Array 3: {P4, P5, P6}.

This is dynamically changing.

In Java, we could have had an array of arraylist and make it work (One of the solutions I can think of). How can we achieve something like this in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so as well in PHP with an array:

```
$array1 = array($P1, $P2);
$array2 = array($P3);
$array3 = array($P4, $P5, $P6);
```

You might want to stack this into another array as well (grouped by score, probably that's what you would think of as "arraylist in java"):

```
$players = array();
foreach(array($P1, ..., $P5) as $player) {
    $score = $player->score;
    $players[$score][] = $player;
}
var_dump($players);
```

However if the value changes within any of the players group the data must be updated:

```
class Pairing
{
  private $players;
  public function __construct(array $players) {
    $this->players = $players;
  }
  public function getPairing() {
    $players = array();
    foreach($this->players as $player) {
      $score = $player->score;
      $players[$score][] = $player;
    }
    return $players;
  }
}

$pairing = new Pairing(array($P1, ..., $P5));
...
var_dump($pairing->getPairing());
```

Or choose the pattern of choice to deal with the events most efficiently.

Comment: I think I was not clear. The arrays need to be created dynamically. In the code you have written, you are specifically declaring 3 separate arrays and adding players.

Comment: Assign your players to the constructor of `Pairing` and each time you call `getPairing()` you will have the actual data. `$P1` to `$p5` to be expected the (updating) player objects. It's always up to date.

Comment: Okie I will try this out. One query, should we do `$players[$score][] = $player;` ? This would always set the 1st element only right? Shouldn't we do `array_push($players[$score][], $player)` ?

Comment: Okay, I was not aware that you want write access to that. This code is to get a array structure for reading the pairing based on players. Just chage the players score to change the pairing.

Comment: `array_push` is the same as `[]` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php (, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: If you want something that automatically updates the array structure, that's transparently possible as well but involves more code. The array then infact is an array and each time it's accessed it will return the "updated" values. // updated the code, there was an error inside the class.

Comment: @darkie15: `$players[$score][]` is not the first object in `$players[$score]`, its the first *unset* object in `$players[$score][]`, so you will always keep adding.